# Load WinForms DataGridView to a WPF control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, datagridview

I have a custom class inheriting from WinForms's DataGridView. It's got it's own styles and probably some custom behavior too. I'm supposed to create a UserControl which has to contain this custom DGV. I'd rather use WPF for that, but unless I find a way to use this DGV in it I'll have to stay with WinForms.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see for [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx). this will host any winform control for you in wpf. you can find a good sample here

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/using-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf/

for example.

```
<Grid>
            <WindowsFormsHost>
                <wf:ListBox x:Name="lstBox"/>
            </WindowsFormsHost>         
 </Grid>
```